# Does DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader cache its moniker map?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Recently we added a "audit_logs" table to the database, and after some frustration I realised that there was already an "auditlog" table in the database for some reason. It wasn't being used so I dropped it. I deleted the Auditlog.pm and AuditLogs.pm files from my schema, and then regenerated. For some reason DCSL again created AuditLogs.pm for the "audit_logs" table, even though there was no longer an "auditlog" table or Auditlog.pm file that would conflict with it.

I have tried just about everything I can think of to get it to generate Log.pm without success. The only thing that I can figure is that it is caching the moniker map somewhere, and I cannot seem to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually tracked this problem down to an issue with the Lingua inflector. It was picking up "logs" as a singular verb instead of a plural noun. This happened because it followed the word "audit" which ends with "it." Basically, I had to write a custom moniker_map function that added an exception for audit_logs.